# Como encerrar uma sessão por inatividade usando Angular7

Tags: angular

Gostaria de encerrar a atividade do usuário se não houver clique em qualquer página da minha aplicação, estou usando Angular e o Nebular.

Comment: Jefferson dá par ser feito com Angular, poderia postar algum código que tenha tentado e colocar mais informações como o período que o usuário fica sem interagir com a tela para disparar a inatividade.

Answer (score 0):

No javascript existe uma função para você fazer isso.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  alert("Teste"); 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Mas eu gostaria que ele identificasse que não houve clique com o mouse, nesse caso funcionaria?

Comment: Acho que essa resposta pode te ajudar:

[IdleTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)